# intercambiar los datos de 2 columnas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy trabajando con SQL, Tengo una tabla con valores

```
columna A    Columna B
    1            A
    2            B
    3            C
```

Lo que quiero es cambiar los datos de la columna B a la columna A para que quede algo así

```
columna A    Columna B
    A            1
    B            2
    C            3
```

¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo? Esto es sólo un ejemplo, las columnas tienen 600 filas.

gracias.

Comment: Esto parece una tarea de escuela. Muestranos que has intentado.

Comment: En un buen código de SQL no tiene relevancia cuantas filas existan. Siempre se debe de pensar en columnas. Hay varias formas de realizar lo que se pide, pero es importante conocer la razón para hacer esto.

Answer (score 1):

Saludos siempre es bueno agregar algo mas de información como tu SQL  que has probado y mas detalles que ayuden a entender mejor y reproducir tu problema y asi dar con una posible respuesta.

En tanto tenemos la tabla siguiente:

```
    Col1     Col2        Col3             Col4  
    -------------------------------------------
     1       aa           a123             abc
     2       bbb          b123             dcf
     3       cc           c7sd             wew3
```

deseamos obtener lo siguiente:

```
Col1    Col2      Col3             Col4  
----------------------------------------
1       aa        abc              a123
2       bbb       dcf              b123
3       cc        wew3             c7sd
```

Como podemos notar deseamos intercambiar los valores de **Col3** a **Col4** y viceversa para lo cual puedes ocupar la siguiente sentencia:

```
UPDATE miTabla
SET Col3 = Col4, 
    Col4 = Col3
```

toma encuenta que esto afectaria a toda la tabla si deseas un elemento en especifico usa el **WHERE**

También hay quienes no se complican tanto y tan solo renombran las columnas esta solución no la he probado pero seria algo así:

```
ALTER TABLE "miTabla"
RENAME COLUMN "Col3" TO "Temp";

ALTER TABLE "miTabla"
RENAME COLUMN "Col4" TO "Col3";

ALTER TABLE "miTabla"
RENAME COLUMN "Temp" TO "Col4";
```

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: La respuesta es muy buena, pero ya le hiciste la tarea. Por eso luego no aprenden.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes valerte de una tabla temporal para lograr el cometido. Para que esto funcione debes asegurarte de incluir la llave primaria dentro del script, ya que es necesario poder identificar unívocamente cada fila.

Asumiré que tu tabla tiene un campo adicional `id` que es la llave primaria, entonces, voy a crear una tabla temporal para almacenar los datos de las columnas que quiero *intercambiar* de manera que pueda hacerlo en una sola sentencia, sin necesidad de agregar una columna adicional a la tabla:

```
select id, ColumnaA, ColumnaB
  into #Intercambio
  from Tabla;

update Tabla
   set   ColumnaA = i.ColumnaB
       , ColumnaB = i.ColumnaA
  from Tabla
       inner join #Intercambio i on i.id = #Tabla.id;
```

Si la tabla tiene muchas filas, puede mejorar el desempeño crear un índice por el `id` en la tabla temporal, en ese caso, antes del update, se puede agregar algo como:

```
create index idx1 on #Intercambio (id);
```